# hide ip address from JSESSIONID

Tags: cookies, wildfly, wildfly-9

When I inspect my web application from the browser I get this cookie:  `JSESSIONID="5Wz6Tjwp74IDYATgzt1W-VP1FmOHMTjmrk4WnbcL.ip-172-39-20-122"`.

I want to remove the IP address from the `JSESSIONID`. I'm using Wildfly 9.0.2.

Comment: how does your apache proxy config look like?

Answer (score 1):

The session id suffix (anything after the dot) is the instance-id attribute in undertow subsystem.
https://wildscribe.github.io/Wildfly/9.0.0.Final/subsystem/undertow/index.html

It defaults to ${jboss.node.name} which you could set on command line using -Djoss.node.name

It's nillable, so you could actually remove it and nothing will be suffixed.